# Json.NET 6.0.4 package installation fails in Class Library project - VS 2013 Premium

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, json.net, nuget

I'm working with VS 2013 Premium, and went to create a C# class library project. Went through the normal notion of installing RestSharp and Newtonsoft.Json (as I'm working with REST calls), when the below error message crept up.

[image: Json.NET error when installing with NuGet]

I haven't seen this before. As an aside - I had to downgrade from Ultimate to Premium about a week ago as my team has the license for Premium.

I tried a few other versions to no avail, and tried via the console and the NuGet package manager.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow. Okay, so it worked after:

1) Closing out VS 2013 and then checking for updates, allowing them to install.

2) Restarting laptop.

I don't know if there is a dependency on Json.NET 6.0.4 or NuGet Package Manager, but I had to install VS 2013 Update 3 to get them working.

Sharing info as an FYI.